# Efficient way to detect white background in image

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, image, optimization

I wrote a script to detect if an image has a white background, by totalling all the pixels that are white and if it exceeds a threshold percentage of the total pixels.

This process takes time and especially long if I have a lot of images. Is there a more efficient way in numpy or opencv that can do it, rather than just using parallel processing?

```
def find_white_background(imgpath, threshold="0.3"):
    """remove images with transparent or white background"""
    imgArr = cv2.imread(imgpath)
    w, h, alpha = imgArr.shape

    total = w * h
    background = np.array([255, 255, 255])

    cnt = 0
    for row in imgArr:
        for pixel in row:
            if np.array_equal(pixel, background):
                cnt += 1

    percent = cnt / total
    if percent >= threshold:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: That's not doing to distinguish between a "proper" background and a foreground with a lot of white mixed in. As an extreme example: is a black-and-white checkerboard a white background with black squares, or a black background with white squares?

Comment: that's fine I think, since the use case is to scrape for images in the web for a particular object, and I dont want that object to be in a white backdrop, which this logic can easily identify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should provide greater efficiency by comparing the entire array to your background color array at once instead of looping.

```
def find_white_background(imgpath, threshold=0.3):
    """remove images with transparent or white background"""
    imgArr = cv2.imread(imgpath)
    background = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    percent = (imgArr == background).sum() / imgArr.size
    if percent >= threshold:
        print(percent)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```